# How to initialize a module class in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a module like this

```
module urlfetch
  class fetch

    def initialize(url)
      @url = url
      analyze!
    end

   #extra methods goes here

  end
end
```

I tried like this

```
response = urlfetch::fetch("http://google.com")
puts response
```

But i'm getting error like `undefined method fetch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

classes and modules in ruby are defined by uppercase names so

```
module Urlfetch
  class Fetch

    def initialize(url)
      @url = url
      analyze!
    end

   #extra methods goes here

  end
end
```

then you initialize a class via the `new` method

```
response = Urlfetch::Fetch.new("http://google.com")
puts response
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, modules and classes should be capitalised, as constants. Secondly, you need `new` to construct an object.

```
URLFetch::Fetch.new("http://google.com")
```